# Do We Really Need Third Party Extension Related Tags?

Tags: discussion, support

We have some third party related to tags in our systems. Some examples are below:

[ecomdev-phpunit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecomdev-phpunit) [fooman-extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fooman-extension)[fishpig](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishpig)[firegento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firegento)[ultimate-module-creator](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-module-creator)[aheadworks-ajaxcartpro](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aheadworks-ajaxcartpro)[avs-fastsimpleimport](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avs-fastsimpleimport)

There may be many more. Some of them are famous and highly used in Magento systems and others are not. However all questions which are related to 3rd party extensions are off-topic in this forum unless if they don't provide us with proper codes.

So in that case, tags which are clearly stands for a third party extension is not allowed in my opinion. Instead of that, OP can use some general tags such as [extensions](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/extensions) [3rd-party-modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party-modules) in those cases ?

Can we completely remove such unwanted tags from our system ?

---

<sup>*P.S : We can retain tags which are related to highly-used/Open-source third party modules. But in my personal opinion, having tags related to a company or a commercial extension kills "equality" in all means.*</sup>

Comment: Same attempt for Magento2 pre-GA tags: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/q/907/3326

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The specific tags are not needed and should be removed. The general tags should remain though.

[EDIT]
Apparently there is no way to delete a tag manually.
It is done each day for tags without questions: [How can we get rid of misspelled and unused (or "zombie") tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19753/224252)

I guess we have to go the long way and remove the tags from the questions.

Comment: how can we remove that ? moderators has privilege to do that ?

Comment: I'm still searching for the delete tag option.

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: will try this today and confirm you.. Thanks once again for your quick reply.

Comment: "I guess we have to go the long way and remove the tags from the questions." that's what I already do. I thought moderators could kill a tag entirely if needed, but seems like you need higher privilgees.

Answer (score 3):

Below the numbers as they currently are. If you're helping out on this, you should also remove the tags from closed questions because if you are tagging your question and try to type in one of the tags you still see them appearing in the suggestions with a >0 count.

- [ecomdev-phpunit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecomdev-phpunit) **-> 49 questions**
- [fooman-extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fooman-extension) -> 0 questions
- [fishpig](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishpig) -> 0 questions
- [firegento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firegento) -> 0 questions
- [ultimate-module-creator](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultimate-module-creator) -> 0 questions
- [aheadworks-ajaxcartpro](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aheadworks-ajaxcartpro) -> 0 questions
- [avs-fastsimpleimport](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avs-fastsimpleimport) **-> 29 questions**
- [magesetup](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magesetup) -> 0 questions
- [magerun](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magerun) **-> 1 questions**