# Vendor names as tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

How to deal with tags the are related to a extension developing companies?

Some used ... [iwd](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iwd)[sagepay](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sagepay)[algolia](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algolia)[fishpig](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fishpig)[m2e](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m2e)[m2epro](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m2epro)

I'd only agree with M2E tags because this is a very unique extension that is widely used.

Comment: I think as we are not allow to do marketing via this tags, then we should delete this tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My take on these is:

- if they are used as synonym for one extension (e.g. [iwd](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iwd) for their onepage checkout, **rename** the tag accordingly, like [iwd-onepage-checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iwd-onepage-checkout). In the past, moderator decision was to not allow extension tags at all (see: [Do We Really Need Third Party Extension Related Tags?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/905/do-we-really-need-third-party-extension-related-tags)), so if this still holds true it means **delete** the tag. But at that time we were more strict about third party extension questions, so maybe this could be re-evaluated.
- if the company is equal to the product or is a third party service that can be integrated in Magento (algolia, m2e, sagepay), it's clear, so no renaming is necessary. Again, if the tags should be allowed at all, that's a different question. I would allow them because I don't consider questions about these topics automatically off topic.
- I can't think of on topic questions about an extension company that are not about a specific extension and would deserve an own tag for the company (e.g. [amasty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amasty) would be a tag I'd just delete)

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [**@fabian answer**](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2337/3535). Along with that, I would love to mention my view on this.

1. I think we should not allow questions which are related to non-open  source extensions. This is because the source code is not available to the community and most of the cases, the question is going to remain unanswered. There can be exception for this if the extension is widely popular among the community and the OP provided sufficient codes to look into the specific issue.
2. In the case of open source extension, my opinion is we should allow such questions here. But it would be better if we can keep them inside a general tags such as [m2-3rd-party-extension](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/m2-3rd-party-extension) instead of creating separate tags for each extensions. This is because the list may grow widely after some time. If we are keeping separate tags, then we should provide the source code link in the description of the tag.

Comment: We already have the tag "extensions" (also "third-party-module" but that one did not receive much popularity), IMHO this should be enough, the tag landscape here is already too fragmented. I don't see benefit in "m2" specific tags as the Magento version is almost always already in the tags. Before introducing a new tag, the question should be, if anybody will likely look actively for questions of this tag.

Comment: Great, if [tag:extensions] available, then we can use it. I put the other tag name here only to tell the tag name should be generic.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion on this is formed by asking, how is this beneficial?

If we look at tags, then we see that it has three main benefits:

1. it can be used in search, combining tags and keywords
2. users that are interested in these topics can set the tags as favorite
3. related questions get properly linked

Another one is that you could earn tag-badges.

Am I right?

Now, having a specific tag for a specific third party module, is that going to help any user on the above? One conclusion that comes back on these discussions about tags is that tags shouldn't be too specific.

As example, if we look at [iwd-onepage-checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iwd-onepage-checkout) this is not really helpful. I would suggest to see if there are broader more generic topics that can be described as tag: [onepage-checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onepage-checkout) in general or [checkout](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/checkout)

Every third party module implements a certain functionality, so **let's have those as a tag** instead of the vendor name or the module name.

Comment: Functionality name is okay with tag, I think problem with just vendor name

Comment: Yes, so I am suggesting to not use vendor names, but only the functionality topic ;)

Comment: agree with you :)